# export 'default' (imported as 'x') was not found in '../x/x' (possible exports: x)

Tags: reactjs

I am pretty confused as to non of the answers I've seen so far really get me closer to solving this issue. I have created a component as the main shell and then have create a calendar component to nest inside of that. When importing Calendar.js to my index.js router it properly runs but when imported into my main shell App.js it won't import correctly or run.

- index.js
- Component

  - App

    - App
  - Component

    - Component

```
import React from 'react';
import Calendar from '../Calendar/Calendar'


export const App = () => {
  return (
    <div>
    <div>This is app</div>
    <Calendar/>
    </div>
  );
}
```

I've taken a look at a few different answers for this issue and received an error similar to this every time.
 `export 'default' (imported as 'Calendar') was not found in '../Calendar/Calendar' (possible exports: Calendar)`
 
`export 'default' (imported as 'Calendar') was not found in '../Calendar' (possible exports: Calendar)`

Comment: Someone in a comment noted that it was helpful for them to pull the directory all the way to root and then navigating all the way back to the component worked. `'../../components/Calendar/Calendar'` No change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import React from 'react';
import { Calendar } from '../Calendar/Calendar'


export const App = () => {
  return (
    <div>
    <div>This is app</div>
    <Calendar/>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Named exports need to be imported through curly brackets.